# postgresql permissions denied

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have just finished install postgres from the way that the postgresql website says for ubuntu20.04

when I run psql I get

```
psql: error: FATAL:  database "myusername" does not exist
```

when I run createdb I get

```
createdb: error: database creation failed: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
```

this is the one command that I have ran from looking online

```
sudo -u postgres createuser myusername
```

it seems to not have done anything though

Comment: Do you recieve any error or output when running `sudo -u postgres createuser myusername`?

Comment: @AlvaroArtano I did not im pretty sure the user got created

Comment: try to do `sudo psql`